# I need to align my toast with respect to a specific view, right now it is with respect to the device dimensions

Tags: android, android-toast

[image]I have a toast which comes on the center of my screen I need to align it to the center of my subview. Currently it is holding the screen view as the parent view I need to assign my subview as the parent view to dynamically change its position

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(toastContext).inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
tv.setText(text);

mToast.setView(v);
mToast.setDuration(duration);
mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);

mToast.show();
```

Comment: What do you mean "align it at the center of my view", what view?,

Comment: Here I have a keyboard view which is smaller than the screen so I need it in the center of my keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This should center it on your text view. You can replace `tv` with whatever view you want to center it over:

```
int x = tv.getLeft() + tv.getWidth()/2;
int y = tv.getTop() + tv.getHeight()/2; 
mToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
```

Note that if your sub view is already on the center of the screen you can use the center gravity and just adjust the y offset from the top: `mToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, tv.getTop());`

Comment: I already tried this but in this case I get the toast on top left for the first time since the parent that it is holding is of the screen rather than my keyboard

Comment: And if I keep on moving my sub view so I need the toast position to dynamically change with respect to my subview

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the view and where the toast needs to be? If you want it to be exactly centered you'll need to determine the coordinates of the view you're trying to center it over

Comment: added the picture

Comment: Sorry, I meant an actual screen shot of the app. This isn't enough information. Could you post the code you're using to display/move your sub view around the parent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect rec = mykeyboardcontainerview.getInputWindowRect;
int xCenter = rect.centerX();

mToast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP, xCenter, 0);
```

This worked for me